# How to load pre-compile Drools rules?

Tags: drools

I am using 6.1.0.Beta3 maven plugin. How do we load the the kbase.cache into KieSession for firing rules. The code below requires compilation jars at runtime.

```
CallRecord callrecord = new CallRecord(new Long(1), new Long(1), new Long(1));
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kc = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession("MapReduceKS");
ksession.insert(callrecord);
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

How do I modify above code so that pre-compiled rules are loaded and I do not required compilation jars at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

It will require drools-compiler anyway since this cache is a KieModule serialized using Google Protocol Buffers format. To deserialize it from this format you will need drools-compiler anyway since classes required for deserealization are there - org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.*